# How to separate interface from implementation in nancy2.0?

Tags: c#, nancy

As you can see at [this link](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#separating-interface-from-implementation), it was possible to separate the rooting and the implementation of the old nancy1.X modules. Now that the way of defining these routes have changed, I would like to know how to code the same separation logic.

For clarity, the old way to define a `Get` route was:

`Get["/{category}"] = parameters => "My category is " + parameters.category;`

and the new way is:

`Get("/{category}", args => "My category is " + args.category);`

The old way to separate interface from implementation was:

```
Get["/favoriteNumber/{value:int}"] = FavoriteNumber;

private dynamic FavoriteNumber (dynamic parameters)
{
    return "So your favorite number is " + parameters.value + "?";
}
```

and the new way is:

`???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with endpoint definitions, you may use either a `Func<dynamic,object>` type specification (#`0` below) or a wrapper for a method (#`1`). That's because there are several overloads of `Get`, so compiler requires these hints to choose proper one. Alternatively if method returns task it can be specified without wrapping (##`2`,`3`), e.g. async methods always return task:

```
    Get("/favoriteNumber0/{value:int}", (Func<dynamic, object>)FavoriteNumberObject);
    Get("/favoriteNumber1/{value:int}", arg => FavoriteNumber(arg));
    Get("/favoriteNumber2/{value:int}", FavoriteNumberTask);
    Get("/favoriteNumber3/{value:int}", FavoriteNumberTaskCt);

...

private object FavoriteNumberObject(dynamic parameters)
{
    return "So your favorite number is " + parameters.value + "?";
}

private string FavoriteNumber(dynamic parameters)
{
    return "So your favorite number is " + parameters.value + "?";
}

private Task<string> FavoriteNumberTask(dynamic parameters)
{
    return Task.FromResult("So your favorite number is " + parameters["value"] + "?");
}

private Task<string> FavoriteNumberTaskCt(dynamic parameters, CancellationToken ctx)
{
    return Task.FromResult("So your favorite number is " + parameters["value"] + "?");
}
```